# Bleu score in python from scratch

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

After watching Andrew Ng's video about [Bleu score](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DejHQYAGb7Q) I wanted to implement one from scratch in python. I wrote the code full in python with numpy sparingly. This is the full code

```
import numpy as np

def n_gram_generator(sentence,n= 2,n_gram= False):
    '''
    N-Gram generator with parameters sentence
    n is for number of n_grams
    The n_gram parameter removes repeating n_grams 
    '''
    sentence = sentence.lower() # converting to lower case
    sent_arr = np.array(sentence.split()) # split to string arrays
    length = len(sent_arr)

    word_list = []
    for i in range(length+1):
        if i < n:
            continue
        word_range = list(range(i-n,i))
        s_list = sent_arr[word_range]
        string = ' '.join(s_list) # converting list to strings
        word_list.append(string) # append to word_list
        if n_gram:
            word_list = list(set(word_list))
    return word_list

def bleu_score(original,machine_translated):
    '''
    Bleu score function given a orginal and a machine translated sentences
    '''
    mt_length = len(machine_translated.split())
    o_length = len(original.split())

    # Brevity Penalty 
    if mt_length>o_length:
        BP=1
    else:
        penality=1-(mt_length/o_length)
        BP=np.exp(penality)

    # calculating precision
    precision_score = []
    for i in range(mt_length):
        original_n_gram = n_gram_generator(original,i)
        machine_n_gram = n_gram_generator(machine_translated,i)
        n_gram_list = list(set(machine_n_gram)) # removes repeating strings

        # counting number of occurence 
        machine_score = 0
        original_score = 0
        for j in n_gram_list:
            machine_count = machine_n_gram.count(j)
            original_count = original_n_gram.count(j)
            machine_score = machine_score+machine_count
            original_score = original_score+original_count

        precision = original_score/machine_score
        precision_score.append(precision)
    precisions_sum = np.array(precision_score).sum()
    avg_precisions_sum=precisions_sum/mt_length
    bleu=BP*np.exp(avg_precisions_sum)
    return bleu

if __name__ == "__main__":
    original = "this is a test"
    bs=bleu_score(original,original)
    print("Bleu Score Original",bs)
```

I tried to test my score with nltk's

```
from nltk.translate.bleu_score import sentence_bleu
reference = [['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']]
candidate = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']
score = sentence_bleu(reference, candidate)
print(score)
```

The problem is my bleu score is about `2.718281` and nltk's is `1`. What am I doing wrong?

Here are some possible reason's:

1) I calculated ngrams with respect to the length of the machine translated sentence. Here from 1 to 4

2) `n_gram_generator` function which I wrote myself and not sure about its accuracy

3) Some how I used wrong function or miscalculated bleu score

Can some one look my code up and tell me where I did the mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your bleu score calculation is wrong.
Issue:

- You have to use clipped precision
- sklearn uses weights for each n gram
- sklearn uses ngrams for n = 1,2,3,4

Corrected code

```
def bleu_score(original,machine_translated):
    '''
    Bleu score function given a orginal and a machine translated sentences
    '''
    mt_length = len(machine_translated.split())
    o_length = len(original.split())

    # Brevity Penalty 
    if mt_length>o_length:
        BP=1
    else:
        penality=1-(mt_length/o_length)
        BP=np.exp(penality)

    # Clipped precision
    clipped_precision_score = []
    for i in range(1, 5):
        original_n_gram = Counter(n_gram_generator(original,i))
        machine_n_gram = Counter(n_gram_generator(machine_translated,i))

        c = sum(machine_n_gram.values())
        for j in machine_n_gram:
            if j in original_n_gram:
                if machine_n_gram[j] > original_n_gram[j]:
                    machine_n_gram[j] = original_n_gram[j]
            else:
                machine_n_gram[j] = 0

        #print (sum(machine_n_gram.values()), c)
        clipped_precision_score.append(sum(machine_n_gram.values())/c)

    #print (clipped_precision_score)

    weights =[0.25]*4

    s = (w_i * math.log(p_i) for w_i, p_i in zip(weights, clipped_precision_score))
    s = BP * math.exp(math.fsum(s))
    return s

original = "It is a guide to action which ensures that the military alwasy obeys the command of the party"
machine_translated = "It is the guiding principle which guarantees the military forces alwasy being under the command of the party"

print (bleu_score(original, machine_translated))
print (sentence_bleu([original.split()], machine_translated.split()))
```

Output:

```
0.27098211583470044
0.27098211583470044
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's slightly modified version of actual `nltk` [source code](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/translate/bleu_score.html):

```
def sentence_bleu_man(
    references,
    hypothesis,
    weights=(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25)):

    # compute modified precision for 1-4 ngrams
    p_numerators = Counter()  
    p_denominators = Counter()  
    hyp_lengths, ref_lengths = 0, 0

    for i, _ in enumerate(weights, start=1):
        p_i = modified_precision(references, hypothesis, i)
        p_numerators[i] += p_i.numerator
        p_denominators[i] += p_i.denominator

    # compute brevity penalty    
    hyp_len = len(hypothesis)
    ref_len = closest_ref_length(references, hyp_len)
    bp = brevity_penalty(ref_len, hyp_len)

    # compute final score
    p_n = [
        Fraction(p_numerators[i], p_denominators[i], 
        _normalize=False)
        for i, _ in enumerate(weights, start=1)
        if p_numerators[i] > 0
    ]
    s = (w_i * math.log(p_i) for w_i, p_i in zip(weights, p_n))
    s = bp * math.exp(math.fsum(s))

    return s
```

We may use an example from the original [paper](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P02-1040):

```
rt_raw = [
'It is a guide to action that ensures that the military will forever heed Party commands',
'It is the guiding principle which guarantees the military forces always being under the command of the Party',
'It is the practical guide for the army always to heed the directions of the party'
]

ct_raw = [
'It is a guide to action which ensures that the military always obeys the commands of the party',
'It is to insure the troops forever hearing the activity guidebook that party direct'
]

def process_trans(t):
    return t.lower().split()

rt = [process_trans(t) for t in rt_raw]
ct = [process_trans(t) for t in ct_raw]

c1, c2 = ct[0], ct[1]

sentence_bleu_man(rt, c2, weights=(.5, .5, 0, 0))
sentence_bleu(rt, c2, weights=(.5, .5, 0, 0))
```

Output:

```
0.18174699151949172
0.18174699151949172
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is revised solution

```
# coding: utf-8

import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
import math
from nltk.translate.bleu_score import sentence_bleu


def n_gram_generator(sentence,n= 2,n_gram= False):
    '''
    N-Gram generator with parameters sentence
    n is for number of n_grams
    The n_gram parameter removes repeating n_grams
    '''
    sentence = sentence.lower()  # converting to lower case
    sent_arr = np.array(sentence.split())  # split to string arrays
    length = len(sent_arr)

    word_list = []
    for i in range(length+1):
        if i < n:
            continue
        word_range = list(range(i-n,i))
        s_list = sent_arr[word_range]
        string = ' '.join(s_list)  # converting list to strings
        word_list.append(string) # append to word_list
        if n_gram:
            word_list = list(set(word_list))
    return word_list


def bleu_score(original, machine_translated):
    '''
    Bleu score function given a orginal and a machine translated sentences
    '''
    mt_length = len(machine_translated.split())
    o_length  = len(original.split())

    # Brevity Penalty
    if mt_length > o_length:
        BP=1
    else:
        penality=1-(mt_length/o_length)
        BP = np.exp(penality)

    # Clipped precision
    clipped_precision_score = []
    for ngram_level in range(1, 5):  # 1-gram to 4-gram
        
        
        original_ngram_list = n_gram_generator(original, ngram_level)
        original_n_gram = Counter(original_ngram_list)
        
        machine_ngram_list = n_gram_generator(machine_translated, ngram_level)
        machine_n_gram = Counter(machine_ngram_list)
        
        
        num_ngrams_in_translation = sum(machine_n_gram.values())  # number of ngrams in translation
        
        # iterate the unique ngrams in translation (candidate)
        for j in machine_n_gram:
            
            if j in original_n_gram:  # if found in reference
                
                if machine_n_gram[j] > original_n_gram[j]:  # CLIPPING - if found in translation more than in source, clip
                    machine_n_gram[j] = original_n_gram[j]
                    
            else:
                machine_n_gram[j] = 0

        #print (sum(machine_n_gram.values()), c)
        clipped_precision_score.append(float(sum(machine_n_gram.values())) / num_ngrams_in_translation)

    #print (clipped_precision_score)

    weights = [0.25]*4

    s = (w_i * math.log(p_i) for w_i, p_i in zip(weights, clipped_precision_score))
    s = BP * math.exp(math.fsum(s))
    return s

original = "It is a guide to action which ensures that the military alwasy obeys the command of the party"
machine_translated = "It is the guiding principle which guarantees the military forces alwasy being under the command of the party"

print (bleu_score(original, machine_translated))
print (sentence_bleu([original.split()], machine_translated.split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that in your code when calculating the brevity penalty you subtract the translation length to the reference length proportion (`mt_length`/`o_length`), which is the opposite of what is done in the [source code](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/translate/bleu_score.py#L82).

The idea is to have a penalty between 0 and 1 for shorter translations, so that the Bleu score is lower in the end, when we do

```
    s = bp * math.exp(math.fsum(s))
```

But with `mt_length`/`o_length` proportion you will end up with the BP growing bigger the shorter the translation is comparing to the reference, consequently having the greater Bleu score too. This is also the reason why your Bleu score could be out of [0:1] bounds (if it is).

So the correct manner to calculate the penalty would be:

```
if mt_length>o_length:  # multiply the final result by 1 (no penalty)
    BP=1
else:
    penality = 1-(o_length/mt_length)
    BP=np.exp(penality)  # get the smaller BP for shorter translations -> more penalty
```